# Error in a class when trying to syncDB (Python Django)

Tags: python, django, class

I am getting an error when trying to syncdb through the command line.

My goal is a basic music search/delete/update/add application with certain criteria and I am using Python and Django.

The class I'm trying to write:

```
from django.db import models

# music search
class musicsearch(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The error traceback:

```
C:\Users\jodie\Desktop\NtokloMH>python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jodie\Desktop\NtokloMH\musicsearch\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class musicsearch(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 168, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
TypeError: contribute_to_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: Hi Martijn Thank you for giving me the heads up on the Stackoverflow ways :) please see amended!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two issues with your model.

You didn't create an instance of the `IntegerField`; you need to call it:

```
id = models.IntegerField()
#                       ^^
```

You are creating *tuples* for the other fields, because you end each field with a comma:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=40),
#                                      ^
```

Remove those commas.

You don't really have to specify your own `id` field; models are by default given an `id` field automatically. See [*Automatic primary fields*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) in the Django models documentation:

> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> ```
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.

Since your specified your own `id` field that *doesn't* use `primary_key=True`, your model is probably going to run into problems with that too.

Comment: I removed them and I am still getting the same thing (I actually tried to put them in there when I got the first error thinking I had missed them out

Comment: Thank you, That has disposed the original error yet created a new one,
ERRORS:
musicsearch.musicsearch: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if
the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.

C:\Users\jodie\Desktop\NtokloMH>

Comment: @akseone: that's already covered in my answer. Just drop the whole `id` line, you don't need it.

Comment: Martijn thank you so much! I can't give you rep yet but I will be sure to come back  through

Answer (score 1):

### Below line of code is missing

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two () for your id integerfield.

```
id = models.IntegerField()
```